# Is there a way to use share embeddable object in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a situation with repeatable class fields which I want to mark as @embeddable, however the question is - does JPA allow re-utilizing a class multiple times as embeddable in other different classes?

E.g. my embeddable class looks as follows:

```
@Embeddable
@Data
public class Audit{
private String name;
private Audit auditor;
private LocalDateTime creationDate;
}
```

Is it possible to embed the Audit into multiple different classes as for ex.:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "BANK")
    public class Bank{
   
    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "BANK_NAME")
    private String bankName;
    
    @Embedded
    private Audit audit;
    }
```

AND

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "CORPORATION")
    public class Corporation{
   
    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "CORPORATION_NAME")
    private String corporationName;
    
    @Embedded
    private Audit audit;
    }
```

Comment: Why not try it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Historically Hibernate called these components. JPA calls them [embeddables](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#embeddables). Either way, the concept is the same: a composition of values.

Most often, embeddable types are used **to group** multiple basic type mappings **and reuse them** across several entities.

Java Code Example:

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "Book")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    private String author;

    private Publisher publisher;

}

@Data
@Embeddable
public static class Publisher {

    @Column(name = "publisher_name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "publisher_country")
    private String country;

}
```

And this is SQL to show how your table should look like:

```
create table Book (
    id bigint not null,
    author varchar(255),
    publisher_country varchar(255),
    publisher_name varchar(255),
    title varchar(255),
    primary key (id)
)
```

More details can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#embeddables) :)